# Is it possible to capture the view in android?

Tags: android

As I am working on paint application.I am displaying the image and paint that image with colors then I want to capture that image .Now I want know is possible to capture the paint image. please provide any code available.

Thanks in advance
teja

Comment: Duplicate: [Save view to JPG or PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that documentation [Android save view to jpg or png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png).
You can fetch the drawing cache and then save that.