# Saving Overlay Image

Tags: android, image, camera, overlay

So I was looking at this thread on how to save an overlay on a picture. [Android save view to jpg or png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png)

I have my code taking the picture and saving the image just like the answer in that thread suggests. The problem is that it's saving just the overlay with a black background. The actual picture that was taken is not part of the image. Here is my code:

```
package com.commonsware.android.skeleton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class SimpleBulbActivity extends Activity {
    private Preview mPreview;
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    FrameLayout preview;
    Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // create a File object for the parent directory
        File imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SimpleBulb/");
        // Check if the directory exists
        if(!imageDirectory.exists()) {
            // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            imageDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Setup the FrameLayout with the Camera Preview Screen
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.preview); 
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    public void snap(View view) {
        mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
      public void onShutter() {
          Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
      }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
      }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera _camera) {
          FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
                // outStream =
                // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
                // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
                // Or write to sdcard
                FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.image);
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
                b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + String.format(
                        "/SimpleBulb/%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis())));
                /*outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + String.format(
                        "/SimpleBulb/%d.jpeg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();*/
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
      }
    };

 // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        SurfaceHolder mHolder;

        Preview(Context context) {
            super(context);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
            // to draw.
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            try {
               mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
               mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                                + data.length);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
            // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
            // important to release it when the activity is paused.
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }


        private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
            double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
            if (sizes == null) return null;

            Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = h;

            // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }

            // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
            if (optimalSize == null) {
                minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
            return optimalSize;
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h);

            Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.height, optimalSize.width);                           
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);                         
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);               
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    }

}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="SimpleBulb Vision"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/bulb" android:src="@drawable/litbulb"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="112dip" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:text="Snap!" android:layout_gravity="center" android:onClick="snap"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476683/save-camerapreview-with-overlay-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm extremely happy to say that I figured this out. For some reason `getDrawingCache()` wouldn't grab the captured image. So I saved the image on the SD Card, placed the image back into the view, and then saved them both as one using the above method. This works well, although some quality is lost due to compressing the image twice. If anyone needs code, feel free to shoot me a message.

Comment: willem: I need code for capture overlay image. Will u send me?

Comment: @user2143817 I no longer have the code. However, the principle is pretty simple.