# NullpointerException when trying to save the current Android app view as image

Tags: android, image, view, nullpointerexception, jpeg

Hi StackOverflow community,

in my application I'd like to have a button which allows the user to capture the current view.

For that reason, I've written the following method (oriented towards: [Android save view to jpg or png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png) ):

```
private LinearLayout container; 

public void createImageOfCurrentView(View v) {
    if (isExternalStoragePresent()) {
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = container.getDrawingCache();

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
          + "/" + getPackageName() + "/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(dir, "image.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos); // NullPointerException!
            Toast.makeText(this, "The current view has been succesfully saved "
              + "as image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unfortunatly an error occured and this "
              + "action failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bacause of lacking access to the storage "
          + "of this device, the current view couldn't be saved as an image.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The problem is according to `LogCat` that there occured a `NullPointerException` when trying to create the `jpeg`. So probably the method `container.getDrawingCache()` is not working. On the phone the file is generated. However with the size of 0 bytes and no visible image. I would appreciate any suggestions what I have to do in order to make it work as I want.

Comment: make sure **b** is not null..

Comment: What do you intent with this line? `container.findViewById(R.id.container);` I'm not familiar with using `findviewbyid` like this, but the common questions (like "is `R.id.container` in the current set view?) probably apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it -

```
public static Bitmap convertViewToBitmap(View view) {
   Bitmap result = null;

   try {
      result = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
      view.draw(new Canvas(result));
   }catch(Exception e) {}    
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it -

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap = bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```