# How can I convert video streaming to images in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm new in here and in android development. I'm trying to convert a video that I receive from an rtsp stream (h.264 I think) to images (any kind of images).

Is there's any way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I haven't started yet because I don't know where I need to start or even what to do, that's why I'm asking if this can be done. Do you know a way to do it? any example? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your requirements are, do you need every frame? However what i would try out is the following:

As far as I can remember you can save any View as jpg or png.
So I would as a first try, play the video using a SurfaceView and then attempt to save the SurfaceView to a file.

Here a [link on how to save a View to jp or png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png).