# Taking screenshot containing custom view

Tags: android

I want to add a feature to an app that takes a screenshot and then allows you to send it (by email etc). I read this this thread:
[Android save view to jpg or png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png)
and the answer works perfectly.

However, when I set the top level linear layout as the view, the image contains everything correctly apart from my custom view, which it just draws as a black square. My custom view is an extension of surface view, the onDraw method is being called from a thread.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make this work?

Comment: AFAIK, `SurfaceView` cannot be captured this way.

Comment: The `SurfaceView` is like a "hole" in your screen. It communicates in other ways with hardware and, as far as I know, cannot be captured.

Comment: have you found solution ?