# Swiping achartengine fragment is a bit laggy

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, achartengine

I use achartengine in a fragment with a view pager. It works great, but if I put a lot of value (100~200) into my series swiping is a bit slow. It's weird because, when I touch the page title, fragment changing is very fast, I only have this problem during slow swiping. How should I solve this?

Additional information:
- linechart with only one series
- y values from 0 to 100
- x values currentTimeInMillis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution we recently implemented is to save the view using the chart engine as a Bitmap and display the bitmap, only re-calculating the chart when values change.

Displaying a bitmap is much cheaper than displaying a chart, your swipe won't lag.

To do it, simply follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png).

Comment: It's a good solution to avoid lagging, but this way I lose scaling. I guess I will start a chartdisplayer activity on touch to be able to scale the chart.