# screenshots in android programmatically without actionbar

Tags: android

I'm trying to apply this code to get a screenshot of a view without an actionbar:

```
 View main = findViewById(R.id.view);
Bitmap screenshot;
main.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(main.getDrawingCache());
main.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

My question is how i can get the view if we don't have a layout,the view is set like:

```
setContentView(new MyView(this));
```

please take a look at this project: 
https://github.com/valerio-bozzolan/AcrylicPaint/blob/master/src/anupam/acrylic/EasyPaint.java
Any help would be very appreciated!

---

UPDATE:

I got java.lang.NullPointerException at this line:

```
View v = new MyView(getBaseContext());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap cachedBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap copyBitmap = cachedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true); // <--- HERE
```

Happy new year!

Comment: You may be trying to grab the view's contents before it has rendered, especially as you don't seem to have put it anywhere yet.

Comment: @Chris Stratton so how to get the view properly?

Comment: At minimum, wait until after you have put it on screen.  And add a null check.

Comment: @Chris Stratton how to get the value of MyView? is it loosing the value if we created a new instance?

Comment: can you provide a code please?

Comment: Forget about trying to capture the view until you have managed to display it by setting it as or inserting it into your content view.  Questions requesting code are generally closed as not fitting with the mission of the site.

Comment: i think it's already displayed (line 82 https://github.com/valerio-bozzolan/AcrylicPaint/blob/master/src/anupam/acrylic/EasyPaint.java)

Comment: Your question must stand on its own, not depend on external links for its basic substance.  The code *in* your question does not display your view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android save view to jpg or png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're assigning the `View` programmatically, then you already have it:

```
View view = new MyView(context);
setContentView(view);
```

Now you can draw contents of `view` into `Bitmap` and save it wherever you want (search for solutions, I don't think it's part of this question).

Comment: it's won't crash if we write it like this ?  View view = new MyView(getBaseContext());

Comment: i used  View view = new MyView(getBaseContext()); and  View view = new MyView(this); and it's crashed in both cases,how i can solve that please?

Comment: @New2Android please provide a stacktrace of crash soI I can see what's wrong.

Comment: @New2Android you did not initialized drawing cache before using it. As I said - search for examples of drawing views into bitmaps.

Comment: I'm bored with that, i'm thinking to take the mBitmap (check the link plz)), but the background would be black (empty) , how to set the canvas as background?

Comment: @New2Android sorry, you're talking completely out of context - it's not clear what's your problem at the moment.

Comment: Can you help me with converting the MyView to bitmap please? I tried different solutions here but always i got a crash.. Thank you!

Comment: @New2Android I'm using this approach which works pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3036736/926907

Comment: View v = new MyView(getBaseContext());
     Bitmap copyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(copyBitmap);
     Drawable bgDrawable =v.getBackground();
     if (bgDrawable!=null) 
         bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
     else 
         canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
     v.draw(canvas);copyBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);   itried both answers but it's crashs.. what's wrong with this please?

Comment: @New2Android either create another question related to your particular problem, or include stacktrace of crash to your question. We're no magicians.

Comment: I give up with MyView, check my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786623/draw-over-a-white-bitmap-another-bitmap  Thank you for your help Dmitry.