# Converting html string to pdf or image in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a **html string** and i want to convert this to **pdf** or **image** file in Android. Is there a way to do such a thing in Android or is there anyone who has done something like this before? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png